# Validate credentials using OAuth

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

Im trying the run the code from `node examples/simple_express3.js` which is given in the link at my project at [Github](https://github.com/ammmir/node-oauth2-provider).

Can anyone explain me what `http://localhost:8081/secret` is trying to do?

How can I connect to my own Authentication server when the client is accessing `http://localhost:8081/login`

Comment: Insert your code, else no one will be able to explain what happens 'with' `secret` to you.

Comment: @ztirom Its given in https://github.com/ammmir/node-oauth2-provider

Comment: You should insert your problems here directly. At your given link we find your complete project. Point exactly to your problem.

Comment: When I hit http://localhost:8081/login as per the node module, the username and password should be validated through my own server before going to the next page.